# random number using Normal distrubution in C++

Tags: c++, boost-random

As [explained by John](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html), I tried this:

```
#include <boost/tr1/random.hpp>

std::tr1::mt19937 eng;  // a core engine class
std::tr1::normal_distribution<double> dist; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    std::cout << dist(eng) << std::endl;
```

But I am getting output as **-1.#IND** which is a [floating point exception](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html) .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me. Normal output.